# MongoNetworkError: connect ETIMEDOUT 3.108.0.179:27017

Tags: mongodb, connection-timeout

I have created a function that handles the connection with multiple mongoDb databases. And it worked well, but suddenly before 3 - 4 weeks the mongoDb started throwing error of connection timeout and reset pool (Below is the full error)

I have whitelisted my IP as well as allowed all IP for now.

```
MongoNetworkError: connect ETIMEDOUT 3.108.0.179:27017
    at connectionFailureError (G:\ALIAN PROJECT\alian-hub-api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:367:20)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (G:\ALIAN PROJECT\alian-hub-api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:290:22)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:629:26)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  cause: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 3.108.0.179:27017
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1495:16) {
    errno: -4039,
    code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '3.108.0.179',
    port: 27017
  },
  connectionGeneration: 0,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
}
```

Sometimes even at the start of my node server it throws this error

here is the configration for connection

```
const connection = await mongoose.createConnection(`${process.env.MONGODB_URL}/${db}`, { maxPoolSize: 60, useNewUrlParser: true, connectTimeoutMS: 50000 })

connection.on('connected', () => {
  logger.info(`MONGO CONNECTION ${db}: connected`);
  console.log(`MONGO CONNECTION ${db}: connected`);
  resolve(connection);
});

  //...Other handers for connection

connection.on('error', (error) => {
  logger.error(`MONGO CONNECTION: error >> ${JSON.stringify(error)}`)
});
```

I also dropped these question in mongoSupport but still no answers found.

Comment: What is the URL?

Comment: mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0.e9ohshd.mongodb.net

I have removed the username and password

Comment: Maybe a problem with your network firewall? Can you connect with other tools, e.g. `mongosh`?

Comment: I am able to make connections and perform the operations in the current config, but in between it disconnects and throws the above provided error

Comment: For the current solution I added a retry login so that It retries the connection for fix time and then at last throws the error if no connection made.

Comment: Well, when you can connect successfully and the connection drops afterwards, then you may have a network problem rather than a problem with your code. Usually the MongoDB drivers reconnect automatically.